# How can I install bioconductor-gviz and use it in jupyter notebook?

Tags: bioconductor, gviz, bioconda, jupyter

I tried to install gviz in a conda environment, but that library seems to be incompatible to python and r. I tried to setup a clean environment using

```
conda create -n r -c conda-forge r-essentials jupyter
```

and then add the library with:

```
source activate r
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-gviz
```

getting

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>     - atk

I remove atk, but now I get:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>     - bioconductor-gviz
>     - r-bindr

Does anyone manage to use gviz from within an jupyter notebook?

I also tried to install gviz from a running R-notebook with:

```
install.package('gviz')
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘gviz’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)

Same when I try 'bioconductor-gviz'.

Comment: The package is from Bioconductor, from the version you are using you should use:`BiocInstall::biocLite("gviz")` to be able to install it from R terminal

Comment: Not sure what that means.

Comment: That to install a package from Bioconductor you need to use a different command (not `install.package`), but the one I provided

Comment: It does not seem to be an accepted command though.Error in `loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘BiocInstall’`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try following the [installation instructions](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Gviz.html)?

Try this in R:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
BiocInstaller::biocLite(c("Gviz"))
```

Comment: Nope, I did not know, each package has its own way of installation. But the first line here was what I was missing.

Comment: All Bioconductor packages are installed the same way. Though in general, reading the software documentation before use is always a good idea. They've changed the command from my answer a bit for R 3.5 and later (see Alex's answer), but for R < 3.5, this is the general way to install any Biocondoctor package.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Install the BiocManager package first
install.packages("BiocManager") 
library("BiocManager")

# Then install the Gviz package
BiocManager::install("Gviz")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use BiocManager::install()

```
# Code
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Gviz", version = "3.8")
```

However, If R < 3.5.0 , please use the following for installing Bioconductor packages.

```
BiocInstaller::biocLite("Gviz")
```